# How to you get the contents of an iFrame to insert into a database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, iframe

I have created a wysiwyg text editor using an iframe and am trying to save the contents of this.

The HTML for my iframe is:

```
<iframe name="richTextField" id="wysiwyg" src="page?page_id=3"></iframe>
```

I am then using a hidden input to submit this to the database:

```
<input type="hidden" id="text_content" name="text_content" value="">
```

I am trying to get the contents of this into the value of the input field using JS like this:

```
$text_content = #wysiwyg.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent;
$("#text_content").attr("value", $text_content);
```

If I set `$text_content` to just a random string it will work but it won't get the contents of the iframe.

I have tried `$("#wysiwyg document body").textContent`, `#wysiwyg.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent` and `richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent`.

`richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent` is actually what I used in the JS for toggling to the source but it will not work when trying to set it as a variable.

Should I be trying to do something like `php serialize()` to get this as a variable I can work with? Or are the terms I've tried as my selectors just wrong? Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the iframe of the same origin as it's context? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @sheriffderek I think so, the page with my iframe and the src file for it are both in the same directory, my js file is in a subdirectory, but I tried inline js on the page with the iframe too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is what I used:

```
richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
```